# Building a website with materializecss and there is a > symbol for one of the selections

Tags: html, materialize

As I'm building a website with a contact page with MaterializeCSS, I decided to use a dropdown menu as one of the selections. The problem I'm experiencing is that there is a ">" symbol to the right of it, which I have no idea how it got there. I am still unfamiliar with building websites so hopefully I explained enough. Code and screenshot follows.

[Image of the ">" symbol on the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owsyv.png)

```
<!-- BEGIN FORM INPUT -->
<div class="row">
    <form class="col s12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6"> <!-- First Name -->
        <input id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
        <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6"> <!-- Last Name -->
        <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate">
        <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"> <!-- Email -->
        <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="email" type="email" class="validate">
        <label for="email" data-error="Please Enter a Valid Email Address" data-success="">Email</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12"> <!-- Drop Down Select -->
        <select>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Please choose one of the following reasons for contacting</option>
        <option value="1"></option>
        <option value="2"></option>
        <option value="3"></option>
        <option value="4"></option>
```

edit: fixed.

Comment: Try to inspect the HTML page.

Comment: What should I be looking for? Looks the same as the source code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you get familiar with using this tool: https://www.cleancss.com/html-beautify

[image]

If you ever have an extra >, it will highlight exactly where it is.

Answer (score -1):

I gone through your code and tested in HTML viewer [here](https://htmledit.squarefree.com/) but not found this unexpected sign. so try to look into some other parts of code may be this is coming from somewhere else, not from the code you have given.